# React: custom select element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Got tired Firefox's ugly select and not being able to style it.
I thought I'd do one in React for learning purposes.

It seems to be easy to implement but I cannot figure out how to do `onChange` with custom component and how to get the value back with the event. If it is possible at all ...

The `Select` component looks like this:

```
type SelectProps = {
  select: {
    value: any
    options: {
      [k: string]: any
    }
  }
}

type SelectState = {
  show: boolean
}

class Select extends Component<SelectProps, SelectState> {
  constructor(props: SelectProps) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      show: false
    }
  }
  label = (v: any): string | undefined => {
    for (var k in this.props.select.options) {
      if (this.props.select.options[k] === v) return k
    }
  }
  change = (i: number) => {
    this.setState({ show: false })
    this.props.select.value = this.props.select.options[this.keys[i]]
  }
  display = () => {
    this.setState({ show: !this.state.show })
  }
  keys = Object.keys(this.props.select.options)
  render() {
    let { show } = this.state
    let { options, value } = this.props.select
    return (
      <div className='select'>
        <button onClick={this.display}>{this.label(value)}</button>
        {!show ? null :
          <ul>
            {this.keys.map((e: string, i: number) => (
              <li key={i} onClick={() => this.change(i)}>{e}</li>)
            )}
          </ul>
        }
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

It works as expected. I can style it (hooray!).

I get the selected value from value parameter. I wondering though if I can get it with `onChange` event? So it behaves more like native select.

P.S.

This is styling of it (in stylus), in case it is needed

```
.select
  display: inline-block
  position: relative
  background: white
  button
    border: .1rem solid black
    min-width: 4rem
    min-height: 1.3rem
  ul
    position: absolute
    top: 100%
    border: .1rem solid black
    border-top: 0
    z-index: 100
    width: 100%
    background: inherit
    li
      text-align: center
      &:hover
        cursor: pointer
        background: grey
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As part of the props, pass in a change callback. In `change`, call the callback and pass in the new value:

```
type SelectProps = {
  select: {
    onChange: any, // change callback
    value: any,
    options: {
      [k: string]: any
    }
  }
}

...
...

change = (i: number) => {
  this.setState({ show: false })
  this.props.select.value = this.props.select.options[this.keys[i]]
  this.props.select.onChange(this.props.select.value); // call it
}
```

Then you can pass your change callback when outputting:

```
let s = {
    value: '2',
    options: {
        '1' : 'one',
        '2' : 'two'  
    },
    onChange : function(val){
        console.log("change to " + val);
    }
};

return (
     <Select select={s} />
);
```